# How I can use curly braces inside a div element in Angular?

Tags: html, css, angular

```
<p>Pattern Format (All Parameters are Optional):</p>
<p>{Parameter: 1, Parameter 2}</p>
```

Above is my code. the second line throws an error because I'm using curly braces in **Angular**. The error goes away if I use '(' braces.

But I want the curly braces printed.
What can I do so that I get the following result in the web UI? -

---

Pattern Format (All Parameters are Optional):

{Parameter: 1, Parameter 2}

---

P.S: I want to print the curly braces.  I'm not trying string interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

Values inside tags must be interpolated, which means surrounded by double curly braces {{ YOUR_VALUE }}.

You can take a look at official documentation to see if it can help
your case, since it's not very clear what are you trying to do.

Guide to interpolation:
https://angular.io/guide/interpolation

If you are trying to write it down you can try with:

```
{{"{Parameter: 1, Parameter 2}"}}
```

Comment: Hey this is not working for the following -
{"A", "B", "C"}

Want to print with the curly braces

Comment: Try with:  {{'{"A","B","C"}'}}

Answer (score 0):

Please check this solution, I hope it will solve your problem.

```
<span>{{'{'}} {{Parameter:1, Parameter 2}} {{'}'}}.</span>
```

Its output will be as:

```
{ParameterValue1, ParameterValue2}
```

If you want to display single bracess **{** only instead of variable, you can use  **ng-non-bindable.**
The **ngNonBindable** directive tells AngularJS not to compile or bind the contents of the current DOM element, including directives on the element itself that have a lower priority than ngNonBindable. Example

```
<div>Normal: {{1 + 2}}</div>
<div ng-non-bindable>Ignored: {{1 + 2}}</div>
```

Output of above will be:

```
Normal: 3
Ignored: {{1 + 2}}
```

When use ngNonBindable it will ignore parentheses in DOM element.

See Documentation [ngNonBindable](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable)

Comment: To print with braces use ```**<div ng-non-bindable>{"A", "B", "C"} </div>**```. it will work, Also see documentations

Answer (score 0):

Just add the @ngNonBindable directive to the element.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).